# Cloudinary:Folder create while fetching remote images

Tags: cloudinary

My images are exist in s3Bucket and i am fetching remote images like

```
s3Url = "http://s3amazon.com/dev/bucket/dev/25287/sample.jpg"

cloudinary.url().transformation(new Transformation().width(200).height(200).crop("scale")).format("webp").type("fetch").generate(s3Url);
```

Images are being successfully stored in my cloudinary account,but i want to store images inside dev folder in cloudinary account.

How can i create folder while fetching remote images ?

Comment: Fetch method doesn't support changing the store path.
You should consider using the [auto-upload](http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_migrate_all_your_images_to_the_cloud) feature which will be much more powerful in your specific use-case.

Comment: Ok thanku very much sir..